# Cant make a popup window to have visible overflow inside a scrollable area

Tags: html, css, overflow, popupwindow

I have some chat container that becomes scrollable at some point.
In this container some text is clickable that pops a window on top of it when clicked.
The thing is that the popup window is being cut when reaching the top boundaries of my chat container.
How can I make the popup overlap the container, so that it is visible no matter what?

My structure is like this :

```
<section id="main_cont">
    <section id="chat_cont">
        <div class="popup_container">
            <span class="popup_text"></span>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>

#main_cont{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#chat_cont{  /*scrollable area*/
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.popup_container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.popup_container .popuptext {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I tried adjusting the z-index (setting popup's z-index higher than the cointainers) but it didnt work either.
The position of the popup is already set to absolute.

Comment: If your container is scrollable, then you’re right, nothing which overflows it will be visible. One option would be, once you display the popup, you scroll the chat container programmatically so that the popup is fully visible. Another option would be to use fixed positioning for the popup, which positions it relative to the viewport rather than to a location in the document.

Comment: I'm already doing what you are suggesting as option 1 , to temporary 'fix' the issue, but best case scenario would be to make the popup overlap the scrollable container.
Making the position fixed wont work out in my case because I need the popup to be relative to the text container. So if  I make the position fixed, when the user scrolls the popup will stay in the same place instead of moving along with the text.
Thank you for your suggestions though!

Comment: Could you add some padding to the scrollable container, to allow more space for the popup?